# external HIT vs. inline HIT on mturk?

Tags: javascript, mechanicalturk

Is there a compelling reason to build an external web-site for a HIT on mturk? That is, if the task is run by javascript on the page, why not simply paste it into the source on mturk and run it there, collect results via their csv? what are the benefits of using an external HIT (which obviously requires getting a server, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you're asking whether you are better to use [QuestionForm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_QuestionFormDataStructureArticle.html), [HTMLQuestion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HTMLQuestionArticle.html), or [ExternalQuestion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_ExternalQuestionArticle.html). More specifically, it sounds like you're trying to decide between HTMLQuestion (where MTurk/AWS host the question for you) or ExternalQuestion (where you provide a URL and host it youself).

HTMLQuestion has the obvious benefit of not requiring any hosting setup of your own. This is the benefit you call out in your question. But it also means that any of the content you provide is relatively static. While you're correct that you can manipulate the user experience with Javascript, it can't call back to your own environment to update information as it goes (say, to look up a value in a directory) nor could it do server-side validation.

This makes the benefit of ExternalQuestion pretty obvious. While it means you're responsible for hosting it yourself, you have complete flexibility. You can create a dynamic client- and server-side experience. Some Requesters also like that they can re-use existing interfaces or systems that they've built, simply be adapting them to MTurk (vs. having to re-write them all as new HTML).

For completeness, QuestionForm is helpful when you neither want to host nor write HTML. You use an MTurk-specific XML language to define your question, and MTurk takes care of all the rendering. This is beneficial when you're not 100% comfortable with HTML or are concerned that you may accidentally break your HITs leading Workers to have a bad experience.

Hope that helps!